# Services don't have MySQL Server. How to run it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mysql, services, mysql5

I need to run MySQL Server on a new for me laptop. There's Windows 7. And MySQL have been installed on it. In order to verify this, I opened the `Programs and Features` window and saw it there:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x42Zm.jpg]

But when I go to the `Services` to run it, I don't find it. It's absent there:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fgr4.jpg]

It's very strange for me. Why MySQL is not among the services? How can I run it? It's installed on this station. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The 2 most likely reasons are either a partially failed installation or that the service is blocked by a corporate Group Policy setting.

Are there any relevant messages in the Event Log?

You could try uninstalling completely and then reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Install the service manually using a command similar to the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld" --install
```

Be sure to read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-start-service.html) carefully, since it goes into a lot more detail.

Comment: This should have happened when he (elevated) installed the product and is unlikely to work.